# Share common locales between pages

Tags: i18next, react-i18next, next-i18next

So in [next-i18next](https://github.com/i18next/next-i18next) it is common to load locales like this:

```
export async function getServerSideProps ({ locale }) {
  return {
    props: {
      ...(await serverSideTranslations(locale, ['home', 'footer', 'header']))
    }
  }
}
```

So what I was wondering (without writing my own wrapper) if next-i18next supports something to load `footer` and `header` for **ALL** pages, because I need them always.

In Next.js you have your `_app.js` I can do as above but that would override the server side translations in other pages.

So I'd like to merge common locales with the specific ones needed in the pages directory.

Thanks in advance!